# Why am I getting blank pdf when downloading using request in python

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I am trying to download a pdf from its URL using the requests.get method and then saving it with a variable name in the local desktop.

However, it takes around 2 minutes to run and the pdf is saved, but the acrobat reader can't read it.

```
from datetime import date

market_type = "ECenter"

market_name = ["Minden", "Porta-Westfalica", "Osnabruck", "Melle", "Bad Nenndorf", "Herford"]

weekNumber = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

city_codes = ["3315", "3317", "3309", "3323", "3325", "3328"]

for city in city_codes:
 url = "https://static.edeka.de/media/handzettel/MINDEN/"+city+"/blaetterkatalog/pdf/complete.pdf"
 myfile = requests.get(url)
 for name in market_name:
  with open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\LeafletFiles\{0}_{1}_{2}.pdf'.format(market_type,name,str(weekNumber)), 'w') as pdf:
    pdf.write(myfile.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `pathlib` module for that. The following code may help you:

```
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path  # import pathlib module
import requests

market_type = "ECenter"

market_name = ["Minden", "Porta-Westfalica", "Osnabruck", "Melle",
               "Bad Nenndorf", "Herford"]

weekNumber = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

city_codes = ["3315", "3317", "3309", "3323", "3325", "3328"]

for city in city_codes:
    url = "https://static.edeka.de/media/handzettel/MINDEN/" + city + "/blaetterkatalog/pdf/complete.pdf"
    myfile = requests.get(url)
    for name in market_name:
        # making our pdf
        pdf = Path('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\LeafletFiles\\{0}_{1}_{2}.pdf'.format(
                market_type, name, str(weekNumber)))
        pdf.write_bytes(myfile.content) # writing the content
```